# Sending S3 Trigger to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a lambda function that has a trigger on PUT in the root of an S3 bucket. My function processes any file put in the bucket, then it moves the file to either a processed or a failed sub-folder depending on success.  I want to be able to move files in bulk back to the root (easy to do via Management Console), but how to I simulate sending an s3 trigger for each file I move so I can re-process the file?  I see how to do it manually via the console, but I would rather write a script to just take a list of files and simulate a trigger for each file.  Can I do this using serverless invoke?

Comment: I was going to recommend [Invoke AWS Lambda function - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-invoke-lambda.html) but it seems that S3 Batch won't work with existing functions that expect a trigger.

Comment: You can probably set the trigger to use "All object create events" rather than just "Put". It will include Copy operations, so 'moving' objects should trigger it.